# 401 error using Authentification on DHL-SOAP API with zeep

Tags: python, api, soap, zeep, dhl

regarding [Authentification on DHL-SOAP API with zeep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212850/authentification-on-dhl-soap-api-with-zeep)

i tried authenticating with the code provided by derAndre. but for me it didn't worked.

i am just trying to get the "getVersion" operation but it failed because of the Authentification.
But if i use it, i get an 401.

```
Server returned response (401) with invalid XML: Invalid XML content received (Space required after the Public Identifier, line 1, column 50).
Content: b'\n\n401 Unauthorized\n\nUnauthorized\nThis server could not verify that you\nare authorized to access the document\nrequested.  Either you supplied the wrong\ncredentials (e.g., bad password), or your\nbrowser doesn\'t understand how to supply\nthe credentials required.\n\n'
```

this is the code, and i'm not getting the hang of it.

```
session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(settings.DHL_SOAP_API_USER,settings.DHL_SOAP_API_PW)
client = Client(settings.DHL_WSDL, transport=Transport(session=session))
# Build Authentification header for API-Endpoint using zeep xsd
header = xsd.Element(
    '{http://test.python-zeep.org}Authentification',
    xsd.ComplexType([
        xsd.Element(
            '{http://test.python-zeep.org}user',
            xsd.String()),
        xsd.Element(
            '{http://test.python-zeep.org}signature',
            xsd.String()),
    ])
)
header_value = header(user=settings.DHL_SOAP_API_USER, signature=settings.DHL_SOAP_API_PW)
result = client.service.getVersion('majorRelease:?', 'minorRelease:?', _soapheaders=[header_value])
```

Comment: How does the service documentation say you should authenticate? Is it with SOAP headers? Is it Basic Authentication in HTTP headers? Before jumping to code, have you tried to get a successful call by using something like [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui/), just to see what kind of request you need to replicate in your code?

Comment: Okay, the Authentification seems to work the problem was, that the header value user / signature must be a different user, provided by the testing environment. Now i have another Problem, but i will first post the question in the DHL community

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar problem and found a solution by following [zeep debugger](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/latest/transport.html#debugging)

Note that, my purpose was to test data via sandbox endpoint: `https://cig.dhl.de/services/sandbox/soap`

However, the debugger said, it was sending request to production endpoint: `https://cig.dhl.de/services/production/soap`

The problem was in the `wsdl` file that I stored `geschaeftskundenversand-api-3.2.2.wsdl` locally.

If you notice, by the end of the file production address has been set to production by default.

```xml
 <soap:address location="https://cig.dhl.de/services/production/soap"/>
```

Just set it to -

```xml
<soap:address location="https://cig.dhl.de/services/sandbox/soap"/>
```

Everything else are okay.

One just needs to make sure that the endpoint is okay. Because credentials are bit different for these two endpoints.

Comment: 6 hours of my life, lost

Comment: what's the status now?

Comment: I mean, I tried using production keys to see if this was the problem before and it didn't work, so even though I changed the .wsdl to use the sandbox endpoint I still changed my code so that zeep creates the .xml payload, which I save to a file and then I send that payload using a requests session. In any case, thank You for Your answer